# Как убрать коллизию у фонового объекта в Corona SDK?

Tags: разработка-игр, lua, coronasdk

У меня есть фоновый объект, который не должен ни с кем взаимодействовать. Я не могу выполнить обычную проверку при касании, так как `event.object2` возвращает таблицу

```
local obj1 = event.object1
local obj2 = event.object2
if((obj1.myName == "asteroid" and obj2.myName == "rocket") or (obj1.myName == "rocket" and obj2.myName == "asteroid")) then
   --my code
end
```

Была идея отключить возможность коллизии с ненужным мне объектом, пытался я это реализовать добавив параметр groupIndex

```
physics.addBody(rocket, "dinamic", {bounce = 0.5, groupIndex = 5})
physics.addBody( asteroid, "dinamic", {bounce = 0.2, groupIndex = 5} )
```

Но проблема осталась.